# Omni-Channel Supervisor Agent Data Visibility

Tags: permissions, omnichannel

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue we are having with data visibility in the Omni-Channel Supervisor tab.

In our dev org we have set up an Omni-Channel Supervisor Configuration. This allows assigned users access to view Omni-Channel info in the Supervisor tab for three different public groups. When I log in as a user, Charles, to whom this configuration is assigned I am able to view the omni-channel data of users who are members of the three public groups I mentioned and not able to view the omni-channel data of users who are not in the in the three public groups. This is working as expected.

We have deployed this supervisor configuration to a qa org and it is not working as expected. When I assign this user configuration to Charles in the qa org, he is able to see the Omni-Channel data for ALL users who log in to Omni-Channel, not just those specified in the three groups.

What could be causing this difference in functionality?

- Charles does not have more permissions in QA than he does in Dev.
- I have changed the OWD on Agent Work in QA to Private as it is in Dev but that has no difference.

I can't figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what caused this to work correctly but I logged in and out as all users and also made sure that all users had the Service Cloud User tick-box checked and in a couple of hours it started working correctly.